# Change Layout on setContentView according to my Internet Connection Status

Tags: android, android-layout, android-broadcastreceiver, setcontentview

I'm currently working on a App, where I want to add a feature. When there is no internet the layout of the activity must change vise-versa. I'm kinda not so good in android and I used this code for my little idea. Any idea how to achieve this. When I try the App crashes.

```
public class RescuingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(ConnectivityStatus.isConnected(getContext())){
            setContentView(R.layout.rescue_page);
        }else {
            setContentView(R.layout.no_connection);
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getContext().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
 }
}
```

Logcat error:

> xxx/E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                  Process: xxx, PID: 6258
>                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx.xxx.xxxxxxx/xxx.xxx.xxxxxxx.view.RescuingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2221)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                      at com.kit.arescue.view.RescuingActivity.onCreate(RescuingActivity.java:90)

Comment: use this in same layout file by visibility

Comment: @JinalPatel any little example with code.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this approach. What's your question?

Comment: take two layout in one xml file which you want and fire listner to hide and show that layouts in broadcast receiver

Comment: @JinalPatel please add code to show this.

Comment: @user13 I'm trying to set layout in setContentView according to the network status. When i'm trying the current code, the app crashes.

Comment: @PrashantGupta because your `Fragment` is not attached yet, so `findFragmentById()` returns `null`.

Comment: @user13 please elaborate or provide code to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, tried working with 2 views.

```
 private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(!ConnectivityStatus.isConnected(getContext())){
            childLayoutRescuingActivity.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            childLayoutNoConnection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            childLayoutRescuingActivity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            childLayoutNoConnection.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
    public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) Login_Page.this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null)
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null)
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      try
                        {
                            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
                            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                            urlc.setConnectTimeout(500); //choose your own timeframe
                            urlc.setReadTimeout(500); //choose your own timeframe
                            urlc.connect();
                            int networkcode2 = urlc.getResponseCode();
                            return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
                        } catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            return (false);  //connectivity exists, but no internet.
                        }
                  }

      }
      return false;
}
```

and dont forget to add the permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Dude I'm trying to set layout in the activity according to the status, not this.!! downvote!!